# How to solve following tree problem?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees

Source of the problem is https://codeforces.com/contest/1152/problem/D . I think i understood the problem , but if possible please explain the problem in simple way and the solution also .I tried very hard to understand the solution mentioned on the website but i was unsuccesful . The problem is  following-

Neko is playing with his toys on the backyard of Aki's house. Aki decided to play a prank on him, by secretly putting catnip into Neko's toys. Unfortunately, he went overboard and put an entire bag of catnip into the toys...

It took Neko an entire day to turn back to normal. Neko reported to Aki that he saw a lot of weird things, including a trie of all correct bracket sequences of length 2n.

The definition of correct bracket sequence is as follows:

The empty sequence is a correct bracket sequence,

If s is a correct bracket sequence, then (s) is a correct bracket sequence,

If s and t are a correct bracket sequence, then st is also a correct bracket sequence.

For example, the strings "(())", "()()" form a correct bracket sequence, while ")(" and "((" not.

Aki then came up with an interesting problem: What is the size of the maximum matching (the largest set of edges such that there are no two edges with a common vertex) in this trie?

solution source  - https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/66696

Please refer to the link for examples .

Comment: Consider a subtree rooted at some node $v$. Either $v$ is matched with one of its children, or it's not (and is then available to be matched with its parent). The size of this subtree is completely described by 2 numbers, namely the height (number of characters remaining) and the "excess" (how much the open-brackets exceed the close-brackets so far). Define $f(n, e, m)$ to be the maximum size of a matching on a trie of height $n$ and with excess $e$, and such that the root either is ($m=1$) or is not ($m=0$) matched to a child. This can be computed recursively, or in $O(n^2)$ time with DP.